# Flot bar charts: configure extent of x-axis when there's only one entry?

Tags: jquery, flot

Anyone know how to define a length for the x-axis in flot bar charts with only 1 entry?

There are 'min' and 'max' options [given in the Flot documentation](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt), but they seem to require absolute values.

By default, the x-axis automatically stretches to fit the values of the entries. From the docs:

```
The options "min"/"max" are the precise minimum/maximum value on the
scale. If you don't specify either of them, a value will automatically
be chosen based on the minimum/maximum data values.
```

On graphs with one entry, the bar is stretching to the full extent of the x-axis, which looks decidedly wrong!

See [an example of the problem](http://data.wheredoesmymoneygo.org/key/to/value/john-hopkins-university).

Comment: Are you talking about the y or x axis? The y-axis is greater than your max value in the example given. ie 250 vs 216

Comment: x-axis - sorry.... have edited question!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Min and Max using an AJAX call or jQuery. Set the Min and Max to one month less and/or one month greater to avoid the bar filling the entire chart area.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but is this an *answer* or a *comment*?

Comment: Partly both. You can set the Min and Max using an AJAX call. However, AP257 does not appear to be setting his data via AJAX, which would leave him setting Min/Max via jQuery. Edited my answer by request.

Comment: It still looks like crap if you do that, but I'm wondering what ideal behaviour would be if you have a 1200px wide graph with one data point...

Comment: @Ryley: yes, I understand your issue.  You could use jQuery to set the width of the Flot div if that was the case.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, change of tack. As you are working with whole day data (apparently) rather than a continuous 'analogue' series I would suggest making this explicit eg...

[Example here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/8j4JM/)

```
  var options = {
      xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: "%y-%b",
        minTickSize: [1, "day"], //we are only working to a resolution of 1 day
        autoscaleMargin: 0.02    //autoscaleMargin solves the issue of bars extending the full width
      },
      yaxis: {
        tickFormatter: suffixFormatter
      },
      legend: {
        position: "nw",
      },
      colors: ["#830242"],
      grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true }
  };
  var data = [
    {
      points: {
        show: true
        },
      lines: {
        show: false,
        fill: 0
        },
      bars: {
        show: true,
        barWidth: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000    //Force the bar to a day-wide (in milliseconds)
      },
    data: [
      [ new Date('2010-04-08T00:00:00Z'), 216359.0 ]
    ]}
  ];
```

Comment: @Ryley Cool, shame that AP257 isn't here. Maybe they've already sussed it out. Can't nudge poeple on SO!

Comment: Don't worry, @AP257 will notice eventually, people don't like leaving un-accepted questions....

Comment: @MichelAyres Hi - The JSFiddle was dependent on the OPs base URL being available which it no longer is....

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, works for me.

```js
            var margin = 0.01; //default

            // If your array has only one value, change the size of margin
            // than, you can have a small column
            if (data.length == 1)
            {
                margin = 3.00;
            }
            
            //Display graph
            $.plot($("#barras"), [ data ] , {
                xaxis: {
                    autoscaleMargin: margin // set the new value
                }

            });
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with flot but consulting the [API](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt) it appears to be possible to configure bar width and alignment. Presumably it is also possible to configure the overall width of the chart. So for example, if your chart is 500px wide, setting `bars` as follows:

```
bars: {
  barWidth: 250,
  align: "center",
  horizontal: false
}
```

should position the single bar in the middle of the x-axis.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work - it still stretches the bar to fill the whole graph :(

Comment: No, but I tested it on the OPs page because I wanted to see if it would work...  I do some dev with flot and this could come up for me...